# lista de aplicaciones instaladas como en el panel de control de un pc Windows

Tags: lista, archivo, powershell

Estamos planteando hacer una aplicación para el control de aplicaciones instaladas en unos cuantos de PCs que tenemos en la oficina.

la cosa es que he encontrado un comando en powershell que lista las aplicaciones instaladas, pero no todos y en muchos casos me muestra huecos en blanco. El comando es el siguiente:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Como bien he dicho no es exactamente lo que se espera. Algo que esperamos es la misma lista que aparece en:

```
Panel de control\Programas\Programas y características
```

Y aunque he investigado no he encontrado nada de donde sacarlo ni si hay algún directorio de donde poder sacar la lista.
En el caso de no poder hacerse con powershell, podríamos adaptar a algún lenguaje de programación que se dijera

Answer (score -1):

Intenta sacar la list con Get-Package.  Ver la respuesta que se presenta aquí.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161112/full-listing-of-installed-programs-using-powershell